# Jekyll HTML heading jump with # scroll is hidden behind header/nav

Tags: css, jekyll

My Site: https://physicys.github.io/Test-2

Site source: https://github.com/Physicys/physicys.github.io

My site automatically generate a Table of Contents based on headings, When I click on the ToC to jump to specific headings, the heading is hidden behind site-header/site-nav.

For example, I'm in "Usage" row but the page doesn't show "Usage" heading.
[image-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soUep.png)

I can see it if I scroll up little bit but then the ToC wil highlighted different row.
[image-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmqe4.png)

I can see the heading is behind the site-header when I remove the site-header completely.
[image-3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlLDi.png)

Expected behaviour: when I click in layout row it will show the layout heading in the content directly (layout row is highlighted and layout heading is visible) pretty much like this site https://0xdf.gitlab.io/2022/12/17/htb-support.html

[image-4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjfrM.png)

I have been messing around with the css site-header/site-nav but nothing work so far.

Comment: Sorry, I can't embed the image directly, 10 rep required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example you gave, this was achieved using kinda tricky solution

CSS:

```
    .post-content h1, .post-content h2 {
    text-align: left;
    height: 143px;
    position: relative;
    color: #DB2C17;
    }

    h2#usage::after {
    content: "usage";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    }
```

HTML:

`<h2 id="usage">&nbsp;</h2>`

this worked for me,

He added height and ::before, in other words, he has the same problem as you, so he made extra space and a fake text at the bottom to be shown as it is spaced perfectly.

Comment: I tested It locally and it works, thank you.
This can be achieve with
```
.page-content h1::before {
    content: " ";
    margin-top: -70px;
    height: 70px;
    display: block;
}
```